# Select few key using map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I have an array which contains man value I am trying to use map method using another array and I want to select few values from first array:

My first array is:

```
    data = [
      "Agriculture, forestry and fishing",
      "Crops",
      "Livestock",
      "Forestry and logging",
      "Fishing and aquaculture",
      "Mining and quarrying",
    ]
```

And my second array is:

```
 b =  [
        {
        id: 1,
        Sector: "Agriculture, forestry and fishing",
        2011-12: 25.7,
        2012-13: 27,
        2013-14: 22.8,
        2014-15: 22,
        2015-16: 21.1,
        2016-17: 20.6,
        created_at: "2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z",
        updated_at: "2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z"
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        Sector: "Crops",
        2011-12: 17.6,
        2012-13: 18.9,
        2013-14: 14.2,
        2014-15: 13.1,
        2015-16: 12.3,
        2016-17: 12.1,
        created_at: "2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z",
        updated_at: "2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z"
        } 

        ....

    ]
```

My full data you can see it here:  [My second data](https://gist.github.com/nwoow/1d29cee3c89f0f6ee771251d5a108aaf)

I am using this code:

```
   @hash_data = data.map{ |vegetable| 
          dataset = vegetable.to_s.gsub("_"," ")
          {
          type: views,
          legendText: dataset,
          showInLegend: true,
          dataPoints: b.map { |value|
          { y: value[_year], label: value[:Sector] }
          }
          }
        }
```

How can I just select values from b array and show only those values which are in my data array.

Comment: Is that the real structure for your hash `b`? Do you have the "year-day" as key (2011-12)?

Comment: _year = "2011-12"

Comment: The `b` hashes have an invalid format. Add a correct one.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nwoow/1d29cee3c89f0f6ee771251d5a108aaf is this wrong

Comment: what is `views`, what is `_year`. Also I would assume dataPoints would have an `x` value too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Regexp.union` passing your data attributes returns a Regexp

```
/Agriculture,\ forestry\ and\ fishing|Crops|Livestock|Forestry\ and\ logging|Fishing\ and\ aquaculture|Mining\ and\ quarrying/
```

that you can use to check every `Section` key within the elements on `b`:

```
b = [...]
data = [
  "Agriculture, forestry and fishing",
  "Crops",
  "Livestock",
  "Forestry and logging",
  "Fishing and aquaculture",
  "Mining and quarrying",
]
regex = Regexp.union(data)

result = b.select { |hash| hash[:Sector] =~ regex }
p result
# [{:id=>1, :Sector=>"Agriculture, forestry and fishing", :"2011-12"=>25.7, :"2012-13"=>27, :"2013-14"=>22.8, :"2014-15"=>22, :"2015-16"=>21.1, :"2016-17"=>20.6, :created_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z", :updated_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z"}, {:id=>2, :Sector=>"Crops", :"2011-12"=>17.6, :"2012-13"=>18.9, :"2013-14"=>14.2, :"2014-15"=>13.1, :"2015-16"=>12.3, :"2016-17"=>12.1, :created_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z", :updated_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z"}, ...]

p result.map { |hash| hash[:Sector] }.sort
# ["Agriculture, forestry and fishing", "Crops", "Fishing and aquaculture", "Forestry and logging", "Livestock", "Mining and quarrying"]
```

Notice this is working with each value on `b` as:

```
{
  id: 1,
  Sector: "Agriculture, forestry and fishing",
  "2011-12": 25.7,
  "2012-13": 27,
  "2013-14": 22.8,
  "2014-15": 22,
  "2015-16": 21.1,
  "2016-17": 20.6,
  created_at: "2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z",
  updated_at: "2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z"
}
```

Comment: can we use b.select { |hash| hash[:Sector] =~ Regexp.union(data) }.map like this

Comment: I'm not really sure what do you need the final `.map` for. Could you explain?

Comment: `data.include?(hash[:Sector])` would probably be more efficient since String regex comparisons are notoriously slow. Also you might want to prebuild the `Regexp` if you plan on sticking with that since right now you are building a new one for each element in `b`

Comment: You're totally right @engineersmnky, forgot to move the regexp outside the block (quite embarrassing). +1 for the `include?` approach, seems to run 4+ faster (Ruby 2.5.0p0).

Answer (score 1):

you can try without **Regexp**:

```
result = b.select{|e| data.include?(e[:Sector])}
p result
#=> [{:id=>1, :Sector=>"Agriculture, forestry and fishing", :"2011-12"=>25.7, :"2012-13"=>27, :"2013-14"=>22.8, :"2014-15"=>22, :"2015-16"=>21.1, :"2016-17"=>20.6, :created_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z", :updated_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z"}, {:id=>2, :Sector=>"Crops", :"2011-12"=>17.6, :"2012-13"=>18.9, :"2013-14"=>14.2, :"2014-15"=>13.1, :"2015-16"=>12.3, :"2016-17"=>12.1, :created_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z", :updated_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z"}, {:id=>3, :Sector=>"Livestock", :"2011-12"=>5, :"2012-13"=>5, :"2013-14"=>5.4, :"2014-15"=>5.7, :"2015-16"=>5.6, :"2016-17"=>5.5, :created_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z", :updated_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z"}, {:id=>4, :Sector=>"Forestry and logging", :"2011-12"=>1.7, :"2012-13"=>1.7, :"2013-14"=>1.7, :"2014-15"=>1.6, :"2015-16"=>1.5, :"2016-17"=>1.4, :created_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z", :updated_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z"}, {:id=>5, :Sector=>"Fishing and aquaculture", :"2011-12"=>1.3, :"2012-13"=>1.5, :"2013-14"=>1.6, :"2014-15"=>1.7, :"2015-16"=>1.7, :"2016-17"=>1.5, :created_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z", :updated_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z"}, {:id=>6, :Sector=>"Mining and quarrying", :"2011-12"=>0.1, :"2012-13"=>0.1, :"2013-14"=>0.5, :"2014-15"=>0.2, :"2015-16"=>0.6, :"2016-17"=>0.5, :created_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z", :updated_at=>"2018-08-23T06:48:27.000Z"}]
```